# Choosing Greater Discount in Magento Cart

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, discount, shopping

We have an extension that creates a bundle discount in the user's shopping cart. This is an overall discount, not a discount on the item level. On the product page, it shows buy x with y and save $40. If a user hits add to cart, it adds both items, but only signifies the discount in the grand total area.

[image: Cart with Bundle Discount]

However, the customer is allowed to still put in a discount code that would further discount the total value. While there isn't an option to stop further rules processing in the extension, I don't want to do that anyway so the customer can still discount items not part of the bundle.

[image: Cart with Bundle Discount and Discount Code]

That being said, is there a way to apply whichever discount is greater between the two? For instance, if the Bundle Discount was $100 and the Discount Code was $80, it would only keep the Bundle Discount. If the Discount Code was $100 and the Bundle Discount was $80, it would remove the Bundle Discount and APPLY the discount code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!